# How to uninstall from wordpress

Tags: wordpress

how do i do a clean uninstall of civicrm from wordpress?  I don't have any data that I need to keep.  Can I just delete the folder and drop the tables from my database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to uninstall Civicrm from your wordpress - then uninstall Civicrm from wordpress plugin list - that should do the work

later you can delete the Database and also CiviCRM folder from your plugin directory.

I guess this helps - Thanks !!!